# CREATE AGG TABLE(T1_ByWeek) from from existing table(T1)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table(T1) with following columns (Date,Shop,Brand,Item,Price). Where I have daily data. I Need to create a new table(T1_ByWeek), where I want to save weekly data. The columns in T1_byWeek should be (WeekNr, Shop, Brand, Item, AvgPriceOfWeek).

Could someone give me hint how to write SQL for T1_ByWeek?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I think your question has been downvoted because this isn't a code writing service.  However we can help you with errors.  Have a go and if it doesn't work post your code here.  Remember to include any error messages you recieve.  Some topics you might want to research include: [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx), [Aggregate Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173454.aspx) and [Date Time Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186724.aspx).

Comment: I used the following SQL which works but I Need another column in T1_ByWeek for week number. Any help  

Insert into [T1_ByWeek]
    Shop
   ,Brand
   ,Item
   ,Price
select
    Shop
   ,Brand
   ,Item
   ,Avg(Price)

   From T1
 Where Date BETWEEN '2016-02-22' and '2016-02-28'
Group by Shop, Brand, Item

Comment: Quick tip for the future, when providing more information edit the original question rather than adding comments.  It's easier for people to see what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to extract the week number from a date.

I've updated your SQL to include.

**Example**

```
Insert into [T1_ByWeek] 
    (
        WeekNr,
        Shop,
        Brand,
        Item,
        Price 
    )
select 
    DATEPART(WEEK, Date), 
    Shop,
    Brand,
    Item,
    Avg(Price) 
From 
    T1 
Where 
    Date BETWEEN '2016-02-22' and '2016-02-28' 
Group by 
    DATEPART(WEEK, Date),
    Shop, 
    Brand, 
    Item
;
```

I can see a small problem with your design.  Each year will have a week 1, 2, 3, etc.  When looking at your table you won't be able to tell if it's week 2 for 2015, 2016 or whenever.  There are a couple of ways you can address this.

*Method One*

Add a year column.  `DATEPART(YEAR, [Date])` will extract the year.

*Method Two*

Replace WeekNr with WeekCommencing.  This will be a date column that always contains the first day of the week.  You can calculate by either adding a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) or by looking for the [MIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms179916.aspx) of date (this only works if you know you will always have sales for every day of the week).

Of the two I prefer the second method, although it is a little harder to build.  Of course you could combine the two and have all three fields.

Comment: Thanks, It works well. Now Question is, I want to run this pro every monday. How should i write where command in this code ( Where Date Between ........?

Comment: You can use [GETDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188383.aspx) to return the current date.  [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186819.aspx) can be used to calculate the start date.  Both return a datetime.  To remove the time portion you can [CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) to date date.  `SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS EndDate, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -6, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS StartDate;`.  Finally you can [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), if it helped!  ;)

Comment: Oh I forgot; If you are running any version except Express you can use the [SQL Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189237.aspx) to schedule your query.

Comment: Thanks @Destination-data. your answer was really usefull. Now i want to update my code accordingly. the process will run Auto every monday. I want to add a delete Statement to be sure that data will not duplicate.

Comment: code: Declare atDate as date = GETDATE() 
 Declare atfirstDay as date = (Select DATEADD(day, -1, atDate))
 Declare atlastDay as date = (Select DATEADD(day, -7, atDate))
 Declare atWeekday as int = ( Select DATEPART ( weekday , atDate ))
 
 If atWeekday != 1 Begin
     Select 'Exit'
     Return
 End
Delete ?????????????

Insert into Table
 From Table . . . .

Comment: Your [DELETE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189835.aspx) statement can use the same [WHERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188047.aspx) clause as your INSERT.  Alternatively you can use a [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.  These are harder to write but allow to combine adds, updates and deletes.  If you get stuck post a new question and we can help.

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers will help those that follow you, by guiding them to a working answer.